# ternary operator returns an unexpected error

Tags: swift

I am studying swift and learnt that I can make an if statement like this `A ? B : C` , I'm practicing it but cant make it, I want to double my `number` till it hits 11, after my `number` is 11 I want code to be stopped with `break` but I get an error

```swift
class Double {
    var number:Int = 0
    init(_ number:Int){
        self.number = number
    }
    func db(){
        for _ in 1...10{
            self.number = self.number + 2
            print(self.number)
            number >= 11 ? break : print("hello")
        }
    }
}
var m = Double(1)
m.db()
```

my code works perfectly when I do it traditional way like this

```swift
if(number >= 11){
 break
}
```

any solution will be appericated <3

Comment: `number >= 11 ? break : print("hello")` This syntax is invalid. The ternary operator can only be used with expressions. `break` is not an expression because it does not return a value. It's a statement.